# A 3'rd party Azure MQTT client for testing

Tags: mqtt

My device is embedded and during devel, it's quite hard to keep modify, recompile especially for connection start. I am looking for a 3'rd party client that works.

MQTTBox is not available anymore, that one from Chrome store isn't working.
I found MQTTX but almost no hints to use with Azure.

MQTTFx cannot be downloaded, they said will give me a link to evaluate which they never did.

I am trying to connect with SAS tokens (no certificates) and to verify this initial part.

Any help, appreciated!

Comment: [Off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) but [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72165612/11810946) or alternatively [mosquitto tools](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things-blog/mosquitto-client-tools-and-azure-iot-hub-the-beginning-of/ba-p/2824717)?

Comment: Google azure iot mqtt lab